# Segmentation fault when writing to comport

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am writing a small program to communicate with a USB to UART bridge (CP210x).

The program is fairly simple, but when ever I decrease the size of the outbound message array below (wm_size < 25) I get a segmentation fault.
The code yielding the segmentation fault looks as follows:

```c
HANDLE prog_com_port;

prog_com_port = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\COM4",
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   //Request Read and Write Acess
                        0,                              //Block others from sharing Acess
                        NULL,                           //Disable Security features
                        OPEN_EXISTING,                  //Only open existing device
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,          //Used to set atributes and flags
                        NULL); 
                                                    //Handle to 
if(prog_com_port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Opening COM port failed - INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE\n");
    CloseHandle(prog_com_port);
    return 1;
}
else
    printf("COM port was opened successfully \n");

SetupCommState(prog_com_port);
Sleep(2);
#define wm_size 25
int messageLength = 2;
char W_message[wm_size] = {0x01,0x01}; 

long unsigned int * bytes_sent;
BOOL Status;

Status = WriteFile(prog_com_port,                       // Handle to the Serial port
                &W_message,                             // Pointer to message buffer
                messageLength,                          // No of bytes to write
                bytes_sent,                             // Pointer to number of bytes written
                NULL);
if(!Status)
{
    printf("Failed to write to COM port - 0x00 \n");
    CloseHandle(prog_com_port);
    return 2;
}



CloseHandle(prog_com_port);
```

My logic tells me that setting wm_size = 2 is enough but apparently that is wrong. Can someone tell me why?

I played around with the size of wm_size and found experiemtally that 25 fixed the problem.

Comment: The pointer `bytes_sent` has an undefined value, and your change seems to hide the error.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I thought WriteFile() pointed *bytes_sent to the address of memory containing the number of bytes sent. And i thought the memory persisted after the program exit WriteFile.

I guess that isn't the case. I'll point bytes_sent to a variable in my programs scope.

Comment: Close voter: it's more than a typo here

Comment: You should revisit your text book what "pass by value" means. You pass a pointer variable `bytes_sent` by value to function `WriteFile`. You cannot get an address out of the function as the function only sees a copy of the uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wm_size = 2`  is enough, the problem is elsewhere: `bytes_sent` is a pointer that points nowhere.

Your "fix" didn't fix anything. You are experiencing *undefined behaviour* (which includes *apparently working fine*).

You want this (all comments are mine):

```
DWORD messageLength = 2;               // use DWORD
DWORD bytes_sent;                      // use DWORD
char W_message[] = {0x01,0x01};        // you don't need wm_size

Status = WriteFile(prog_com_port,
                W_message,             // remove &, W_message decays into a pointer
                messageLength,
                &bytes_sent,           // put &, you need a pointer here
                NULL);
```

or even better: you don't need `messageLength`:

```
Status = WriteFile(prog_com_port,
                W_message,              // remove &
                sizeof(W_message),      // assuming W_message contains chars
                &bytes_sent,            // put &
                NULL);

// now bytes_sent contains the number of bytes sent (hopefully 2),
// providing WriteFile succeeded (Status is TRUE)
```

The usage of `DWORD` is highly recommended, so the types of the arguments passed to to `WriteFile` actually match the declaration (and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile)). Also be aware that `LPDWORD` in all Microsoft documentation and header files is is the
same thing as `DWORD*`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed input! - I have an additional question: Why is it bad form to use & when referencing the first index of an array?

Comment: @CasperKnudsen it's not bad, it's just unnecessary because an array decays automatically into the pointer to it's first element. Assuming you have `char foo[] = "bar";`, `foo`, `&foo` and `&foo[0]` are the same thing.